# How to add an associative array as a single new item into an already existing array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I have forms in my site with some questions for the users to fill.
After each form gets submitted, all the information submitted is added into an associative array.

After that I encode that array as JSON, and save it into a single field in a MySQL database.

The user may complete many forms, and I want to add every array (with the information of that single filled in form by that user), to be added to the array that's already stored in the database as a JSON string. As a new item in that array.

For example:

### array 1:

```
array { 
    ["examenID"]=> string(1) "4" 
    ["cursoID"]=> string(2) "15" 
    ["fechaExamen"]=> string(22) "04-10-2016 11:23:39 AM" 
    ["pregunta"]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> string(18) "el azul es azulado" 
        [1]=> string(28) "el verde es azulado también" 
    } 
    ["respuestaCorrecta"]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> string(1) "v" 
        [1]=> string(1) "f" 
    } 
    ["respuestaUsuario"]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> string(1) "v" 
        [1]=> string(1) "f" 
    } 
    ["puntaje"]=> int(2) 
    ["estado"]=> string(8) "APROBADO" 
}
```

### array 2:

```
array { 
    ["examenID"]=> string(1) "6" 
    ["cursoID"]=> string(2) "15" 
    ["fechaExamen"]=> string(22) "03-10-2016 10:20:40 AM" 
    ["pregunta"]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> string(18) "el negro es blanco" 
        [1]=> string(28) "el negro es negro" 
        [2]=> string(28) "los colores son distintos" 
    } 
    ["respuestaCorrecta"]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> string(1) "f" 
        [1]=> string(1) "v" 
        [2]=> string(1) "v" 
    } 
    ["respuestaUsuario"]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> string(1) "f" 
        [1]=> string(1) "f" 
        [2]=> string(1) "f" 
    } 
    ["puntaje"]=> int(1) 
    ["estado"]=> string(8) "DESAPROBADO" 
}
```

**I would like to merge both of them, so it results in this:**

```
[0]    array { 
        ["examenID"]=> string(1) "4" 
        ["cursoID"]=> string(2) "15" 
        ["fechaExamen"]=> string(22) "04-10-2016 11:23:39 AM" 
        ["pregunta"]=> array(2) { 
            [0]=> string(18) "el azul es azulado" 
            [1]=> string(28) "el verde es azulado también" 
        } 
        ["respuestaCorrecta"]=> array(2) { 
            [0]=> string(1) "v" 
            [1]=> string(1) "f" 
        } 
        ["respuestaUsuario"]=> array(2) { 
            [0]=> string(1) "v" 
            [1]=> string(1) "f" 
        } 
        ["puntaje"]=> int(2) 
        ["estado"]=> string(8) "APROBADO" 
    } 

[1]   array { 
        ["examenID"]=> string(1) "6" 
        ["cursoID"]=> string(2) "15" 
        ["fechaExamen"]=> string(22) "03-10-2016 10:20:40 AM" 
        ["pregunta"]=> array(2) { 
            [0]=> string(18) "el negro es blanco" 
            [1]=> string(28) "el negro es negro" 
            [2]=> string(28) "los colores son distintos" 
        } 
        ["respuestaCorrecta"]=> array(2) { 
            [0]=> string(1) "f" 
            [1]=> string(1) "v" 
            [2]=> string(1) "v" 
        } 
        ["respuestaUsuario"]=> array(2) { 
            [0]=> string(1) "f" 
            [1]=> string(1) "f" 
            [2]=> string(1) "f" 
        } 
        ["puntaje"]=> int(1) 
        ["estado"]=> string(8) "DESAPROBADO" 
    }
```

**I've tried this:**

```
        $total[] = $array1;
        $total[] = $array2;
```

But the problem is that the first time the user fills the form, it is filled as a single item. The second time it is filled as a second item, but after the third time, the new item is not stored in the expected way.

**After the third time, the array gets like this, which breaks the structure:**

```
array(2) { 
    [0]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> array(2) { //WHY?
            [0]=> NULL // WHY?
            [1]=> array(8) { 
                ["examenID"]=> string(1) "4" 
                ["cursoID"]=> string(2) "15" 
                ["fechaExamen"]=> string(22) "04-10-2016 11:59:48 AM" 
                ["pregunta"]=> array(2) { 
                    [0]=> string(18) "el azul es azulado" 
                    [1]=> string(28) "el verde es azulado también" 
                } 
                ["respuestaCorrecta"]=> array(2) { 
                    [0]=> string(1) "v" 
                    [1]=> string(1) "f" 
                } 
                ["respuestaUsuario"]=> array(2) { 
                    [0]=> string(1) "v" 
                    [1]=> string(1) "v" 
                } 
                ["puntaje"]=> int(1) 
                ["estado"]=> string(8) "APROBADO" 
            } 
        } 
        [1]=> array(8) { 
            ["examenID"]=> string(1) "3" 
            ["cursoID"]=> string(2) "15" 
            ["fechaExamen"]=> string(22) "04-10-2016 11:59:56 AM" 
            ["pregunta"]=> array(3) { 
                [0]=> string(42) "El caballo blanco de San Martin era blanco" 
                [1]=> string(15) "La sal es dulce" 
                [2]=> string(19) "La lluvia es mojada" 
            } 
            ["respuestaCorrecta"]=> array(3) { 
                [0]=> string(1) "v" 
                [1]=> string(1) "f" 
                [2]=> string(1) "v" 
            } 
            ["respuestaUsuario"]=> array(3) { 
                [0]=> string(1) "f" 
                [1]=> string(1) "f" 
                [2]=> string(1) "f" 
            } ["puntaje"]=> int(1) 
            ["estado"]=> string(11) "DESAPROBADO" 
        } 
    } 
    [1]=> array(8) { 
        ["examenID"]=> string(1) "4" 
        ["cursoID"]=> string(2) "15" 
        ["fechaExamen"]=> string(22) "04-10-2016 12:00:03 PM" 
        ["pregunta"]=> array(2) { 
            [0]=> string(18) "el azul es azulado" 
            [1]=> string(28) "el verde es azulado también" 
        } 
        ["respuestaCorrecta"]=> array(2) { 
            [0]=> string(1) "v" 
            [1]=> string(1) "f" 
        } 
        ["respuestaUsuario"]=> array(2) { 
            [0]=> string(1) "f" 
            [1]=> string(1) "f" 
        } 
        ["puntaje"]=> int(1) 
        ["estado"]=> string(8) "APROBADO" 
    } 
}
```

### Here is what I'm doing:

I'm querying the database, and fetching a specific result (the field "examenes"). The first time, the item fetched is a NULL field when the user didn't completed any form yet.

```
  $resultado = $mostrarExamen2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $respuestasAnteriores = json_decode($resultado['examenes'], true);
```

**When the user submit the form:**

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

        for ($i = 0; $i < $cant; $i++) {

            $ru = $_POST['respuestaUsuario'][$i];
                $respuestasUsuario['examenID'] = $examenID;
                $respuestasUsuario['cursoID'] = $cursoID;
                $respuestasUsuario['fechaExamen'] = $fechaExamen;
                $respuestasUsuario['pregunta'] = $_POST['pregunta'];
                $respuestasUsuario['respuestaCorrecta'] = $_POST['rc'];

                if ($ru == 'verdadero') {
                    $respuestasUsuario['respuestaUsuario'][] = 'v';
                } else if ($ru == 'falso') {
                    $respuestasUsuario['respuestaUsuario'][] = 'f';
                }
        }

                //hacemos el cálculo del examen para saber si aprobó o no
                $puntaje = 0;
                for ($i = 0; $i < $cant; $i++) {
                    $rc = $respuestasUsuario['respuestaCorrecta'][$i];
                    $ru = $respuestasUsuario['respuestaUsuario'][$i];
                    if ($rc == $ru) {
                        $puntaje++;
                    }
                }

                echo '<br>Examen Enviado.<br>';
                echo 'Puntaje Obtenido: '.$puntaje.'<br>';

                if ($puntaje >= $examen['puntajeTotal']) {
                    $estado = 'APROBADO';
                    echo 'Examen APROBADO<br>';
                } else {
                    $estado = 'DESAPROBADO';
                    echo 'Examen DESAPROBADO<br>';
                }

                $respuestasUsuario['puntaje'] = $puntaje;
                $respuestasUsuario['estado'] = $estado;



                $total[] = $respuestasAnteriores;
                $total[] = $respuestasUsuario;
```

The thing is that `$respuestasAnteriores` already is an array, and where it already has more than one element in it, the next one that is added up to it breaks the structure.

Comment: $total[] should work, we need more of your code to answer. Try with array_push but it should be the same.

Comment: So if you do $respuestasAnteriores[] = json_decode($resultado['examenes'], true); it will work correctly but with an useless array level ??

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array();

array_push($array, $array1, $array2);
```

**Like this:**

```
$array = array();

$array1 = array(
    'something' => 'somthing',
    array(
        'something' => 'somthing',
        array('something' => 'somthing'),
        array('something' => 'somthing'),
        array('something' => 'somthing')
    ),
    'something' => 'somthing'
);

$array2 = array(
    'somewhere' => 'somewhere',
    array(
        'somewhere' => 'somewhere',
        array('somewhere' => 'somewhere'),
        array('somewhere' => 'somewhere'),
        array('somewhere' => 'somewhere')
    ),
    'somewhere' => 'somewhere'
);

array_push($array, $array1, $array2);

print_r($array);

?>
```

**Outputs:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [something] => somthing
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [something] => somthing
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [something] => somthing
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [something] => somthing
                        )
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [something] => somthing
                        )
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [somewhere] => somewhere
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [somewhere] => somewhere
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [somewhere] => somewhere
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [somewhere] => somewhere
                        )
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [somewhere] => somewhere
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

So in your case:

```
$total = array();
array_push($total, $respuestasAnteriores, $respuestasUsuario);
```

Answer (score -3):

The only thing you need to do is:

```
 $total[] = {$array1, $array2}
```